# how to extract integer value on textview to another integer inside listview onclicklistener

Tags: android, json, android-listview

I working on an Android project which has a `ListView` and contains one `TextView` to display the contact and contact are stored in my website in form of json.

[json link for contacts](http://www.iamnotcrazy.hol.es/webservice/contact.php)

I am able to parse the contacts I have no problem with that. But the problem is the parsed data is displayed as a number like "776057619" in the `TextView` and I want this `TextView` number to be taken and stored in a separate variable. By doing this I can use it to prompt the user "weather you want to call  that particular number"??. But I don't no how to pull that number from the `TextView` to a separate variable and use to call inside `ListView`'s `OnItemClickListener`

**below is my code**

```
public class Contactmedia extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private static final String READ_CONTACT_URL = "http://www.iamnotcrazy.hol.es/webservice/contact.php";

    private static final String TAG_NUMBER ="number";
    private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";

    private JSONArray mid = null;
    //manages all of our comments in a list.
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mContactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.contactmedialist);   
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        new LoadComments().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves json data of comments
     */
    public void updateJSONdata() {
        mContactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(READ_CONTACT_URL);

        try { 

            mid= json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

            for (int i = 0; i < mid.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = mid.getJSONObject(i);            
                String number = c.getString(TAG_NUMBER);
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();                 
                map.put(TAG_NUMBER, number);  
                mContactList.add(map);     
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the parsed data into our listview
     */
    private void updateList() {

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mContactList,
                R.layout.contactmediadesign, new String[] { TAG_NUMBER
                         }, new int[] { R.id.contactno 
                        });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        ListView lv = getListView();    
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                /* this is where i have problem how to get  that number without converting to string*/
                TextView v = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.contactno); 
                int myNum = Integer.parseInt(v.getText().toString());
                /* and here i want use that mynum after getiing phonenumber for calling purpouse ass shown below 
                 * but its not working :(*/
                if (position == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yes you done it!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);  
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+"myNum"));  
                    startActivity(callIntent);
                }

            }
        });
    }       

    public class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Contactmedia.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading complaints...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

              updateJSONdata();

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();

            updateList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "its not working". What is/isn't it doing? Any errors? Also, you really should spend more time formatting your posts so they are easier to read. And stack snippets aren't for this type of code. Use code blocks instead

Answer (score 0):

Since you actually need string, you don't have to convert to integer at all:

```
TextView v = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.contactno); 
...
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ v.getText().toString()));
```

or if you do need to store that number in variable for some reason, you should use `String` instead

```
TextView v = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.contactno); 
string myNum = v.getText().toString();
...
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + myNum));
```

Comment: it worked form me!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! tank you thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting the data associated with that position rather than trying to parse the view to get it.

You can get the data from the `adapter` with [`adapter.getItem(int pos)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem(int)). Just make `adapter` final or a member variable to access it in the `OnItemClickListener`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check your Manifest file, you should have this outside the "application" tag but within the "manifest" tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Try to do something like this in your code:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + v.getText().toString()));
        startActivity(callIntent);
```

You should use String value instead of int

Answer (score 0):

remove the double quotation on mynum. you can also use basic oop to save your integer value. fyi, myNum doesnt have to be an integer. it can be a string

```
ListView lv = getListView();    
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            /* this is where i have problem how to get  that number without converting to string*/
            TextView v = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.contactno); 
            int myNum = Integer.parseInt(v.getText().toString());

            setNumber(myNum); //saving the myNum variable 
            System.out.println("number is: " + getNumber());//if you want to get the value of myNum, just call the getNumber()

                     if (position == 0){
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yes you done it!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL); 

                       callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ myNum));//remove the quotation for myNum

                      startActivity(callIntent);
                     }

        }



private int number;
void setNumber(int number){
    this.number=number;
}

int getNumber(){
    return number;
}
```